Nodemailer отправить письмо с прокси
Не могу отправить письмо через Nodemailer с прокси с аутентификацией. Пишет ошибку: Socks5 proxy rejected connection - ConnectionRefused. Если не юзать прокси, то всё работает. Код (данные конечно мои валидные):
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true для порта 465, false для других портов
    auth: {
        user: 'test@gmail.com',
        pass: 'zzxxcc'
    },
    proxy: 'socks://user:pass@138.59.1.1:5555'
});

transporter.set('proxy_socks_module', require('socks'));

let mailOptions = {
  from: "test@gmail.com",
  to: "priem@gmail.com",
  subject: "theme",
  text: "hi"
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        ended = error.message;
        resolve()
    } else {
        ended = 1;
        resolve()
    }
});


прокси точно рабочий? на 138.59.1.1 нет открытого порта 5555

@nörbörnën , всё рабочее. написал выше что данные изменены

Надо проверить (если есть доступ) что на узле с proxy не закрыт 25 порт. Обычно хостеры их блокируют, защита от спамеров.
